# MySQL Query Bug?

Tags: mysql, sql

I do that query that should return me 5 query but I get 10...

```
SELECT *
FROM article ar, account ac
WHERE ar.approved = '1'
AND ar.author = ac.id
ORDER BY ar.id DESC
LIMIT 5 , 10
```

Showing rows 0 - 9 (10 total, Query took 0.0028 sec)

What am I doing wrong? It was working fine before...

Comment: You are asking for 10 rows.  If you want 5 rows, use `LIMIT 5, 5,`.

Comment: Mention what is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mySQL [`LIMIT X, Y`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) means

- `X` is starting element (offset)
- `Y` is number of elements that you want to be returned

that's why you're getting 10 rows back.

If you only want 5 rows back and you need 5 first rows to be skipped, you should use `LIMIT 5, 5`.

Comment: Thanks that was the issue. I tough it was working another way. I will accept it as answer in 10 min.

Answer (score 0):

As you need only 5 rows and you need to skip the first 5 rows use:
    LIMIT(5,5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM article ar, account ac
WHERE ar.approved = '1'
AND ar.author = ac.id
LIMIT 5, 10
ORDER BY ar.id DESC
```

Here is the grammer:

1. The `offset`(**5**) specifies the **offset of the first row to return**. The
   `offset` of the first row is 0, not 1.
2. The `count`(**10**) specifies **maximum number of rows to return**.